# discord.js want to set database for all guild member

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, read-eval-print-loop, replit

I need to set the bank database for all server members as 10000 and here is my code

```js
client.on('message', async message => {

  if (message.content === '#bank') {

    var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('644523866638647316');

    await db.set(`bank_${guild.member}`, 10000)

  }

})
```

Comment: Hello, some extra information would be nice, such as what database library you are using **IE** the `db` variable, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) contains a [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) property, which is a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager). You can loop through each member in this group using the following:

```js
guild.members.cache.each((member) => {
  // you might want to use member.id, rather than just member here
  db.set(`bank_${member}`, 10000);
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work i tried it and checked a members database it wont work , ineed to add 10000 to all members of the servers database

Comment: I think there is a `db.add` function instead of `db.set`?

Comment: uhm idont think

Comment: ineed away to set all of the server members at the same time instead off setting 1 by 1